# how to define models, validators, expiring URL, by using Following data?

Tags: django-rest-framework

id auto increment
Name : source name (unique)  mk
Desc : small descripton to know about sourc
rooturl : domain Name that deployed this tinny url https://tm.py/
Active/Expired: Bool
Createdon
CreatedBy

Tinny URL tables

id, : auto
sourcecode : source table code mk
tinnycode : generated 6 digits code ( should be unique for source) A123h5
MainURL : actual url
tinnyURL: tinney https://tkm.py/A123h5
validity : no of days valid from created date
Createdon : auto
createdby : request by
RequestFrom : request header info ( Like IP,request url, user etc)

setTinnyURL( Source, actual URL, validity)

soruce :Mk
actual URL :
[https://airbrake.io/blog/python/zerodivisionerror-2#:~:text=As%20you%20may%20suspect%2C%20the,or%20modulo](https://airbrake.io/blog/python/zerodivisionerror-2#:%7E:text=As%20you%20may%20suspect%2C%20the,or%20modulo))%20operation%20was%20zero.&text=We'll%20also%20see%20how,handling%20division%20by%20zero%20issues.

validity : 3

log ( "got tinney request for MK soruce", "IP",USr)
generate Tunney code 6 unique A123h5

{
status: 200
message": success

```
response:{
        TinnyURL: "https://tkm.py/A123h5"
}
```

}

getTinnyURL(tinnyURL)
check  tinnyurl in  Tinny URL tables , value matched in tinnyURL field then retun actualURL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to define model of source field and tinyurlfield and make relationship Between the first source code table to second source code table